# Workaround for 'Snowflake only supports a single security integration from a single Azure AD tenant'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am sharing a solution as I think this will be useful for others.

After following the instructions at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html to integrate our Azure AD with Oauth to Snowflake, we got a problem. Snowflake only supports one security integration per AAD tenant.

Since we wanted to use both integration on the client level and on the user level;

```
create security integration (...) 
   external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'sub' 
vs
   external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
```

To get around this we created two custom policies in AAD:

```
    New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"application","ID":"objectid","JwtClaimType":"sfuser"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "SnowflakeUserObjectClaims" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

and

```
 New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"userprincipalname","JwtClaimType":"sfuser"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "SnowflakeUserUpnClaims" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

These could then be associated with one application registration for the application and another for the user ('Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy'). In other words, the claims from each of these would always include the 'sfuser' claim. This also requires a manual change in the application manifest:

```
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
```

We could now create the security integration in Snowflake, with our new claim:

```
  create security integration (...) 
      external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'sfuser'
```

And Snowflake was able to use the new claim to authenticate requests from both our app.registrations.

Answer (score 0):

Adding for posterity. This field accepts a list. I used the following:

```
 ALTER SECURITY INTEGRATION sample_integration SET EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN_USER_MAPPING_CLAIM = ('sub','upn');
```